# Cambio de pantalla con Navigator en Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy intentando utilizar Navigator en Flutter para hacer un cambio de pantalla como lo dice la documentación [Navigate to second screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) pero obtengo este error:

```
Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
```

Intento crear un ListView y en cada ListView agregar un elemento que al hacer click va desplegar a una segunda pantalla, también si fueran tan amables de brindarme una forma de pasar variables de la primera pantalla a la segunda pantalla.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
class Numeria extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Numeria, el rincón de los ingenieros',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Numeria'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                    title: Text('Matemáticas'),
                    subtitle: Text(
                        'Álgebra, Geometría, Trigonometría, Derivadas, Integrales y más'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                    title: Text('Física'),
                    subtitle: Text('Cinematica, Dinamica, Estatica y más'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                    title: Text('Química'),
                    subtitle:
                        Text('Solubilidad, Temperatura, Estiquiometría y más'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                    title: Text('Informática'),
                    subtitle:
                        Text('Estructuras, Algoritmos básicos, comandos y más'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                    title: Text('Constantes'),
                    subtitle: Text('Constantes fisicas universales'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to first route when tapped.
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy iniciando en Flutter, creo que el problema tiene que ver con que no puede acceder a la instancia de Navigator, pero no estoy seguro de cómo resolverlo o como pasarle la instancia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error clásico, el tema es que tienes el `MaterialApp` dentro del widget donde estás usando el `Navigator`, necesitas que el padre del contexto que usas tenga asociado el `Navigator`. Lo puedes solucionar de 2 formas.

1- Crea un nuevo widget `Stateless` o `Stateful` y pon todo lo que está dentro de `home:` ahí.

Ahí podrás invocar al `Navigator` sin problemas, ya que el contexto de ese widget, tendrá un `Navigator` como parent.

2- Dentro de `home` usa el widget `Builder` , te quedaría algo así .

```dart
home : Builder (builder: (nuevoContext) {

        return Scaffold (...);
       }
)
```

Y al momento de usar el `Navigator.push`, usa el contexto nuevo:

```dart
Navigator.push(
              nuevoContext,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
);
```

Comment: Gracias me ayudo